# Display Actual Method Name In Log

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I've been using Serilog inside a .net core webapi project and am able to happily use it. However, an example I want to include in the information log the method name - accessing the class name is ok using SourceContext.

However, following various suggestions / guides online I added an enricher but the result each time is the actual Enrich method.

To summarize my knowledge, I've come from a primarily .net 3.5 and below background so everything beyond this is a very steep learning curve at the moment. Please be gentle :-)

I have tried both:

```
logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(new LogEventProperty("MethodName", new ScalarValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name)));
```

and

```
logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(new LogEventProperty("MethodName", new ScalarValue(GetActualAsyncMethodName())));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have fixed this by adding an action filter and adding a property to the LogContext for Serilog as follows:

```
    public class LoggingPropertiesFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            // Do something before the action executes.
            ControllerBase controllerBase = context.Controller as ControllerBase;
            if(controllerBase != null)
            {
                var routeAction = controllerBase.RouteData.Values["action"];

                LogContext.PushProperty("method", routeAction);

            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // Do something after the action executes.
        }
    }
```

The only issue I have with this so far is that I have to manually attach an attribute to each action for this to work, but this does solve the initial problem I had if it's any use to anyone.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use below code in action:

```
var methodname = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
```

Comment: Thanks Xing Zou, however, as this is being called from an encricher class, this doesn't work as the controllercontext isn't accessible from here.